# In a dataframe, I want to compare column A and column B and extract value in which A >= B?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
Cars         A      B
Honda        5      3     
Kia          7      5
BMW          4      8
Mazda        6      10
Hyundai      15     12
Lexus        22     19
Toyota       40     50
Jeep         60     50
```

The above figure is my dataframe. From this i want to compare column A with column B and extract values in A which are greater or equals to B (A>=B).

I tried to solve this by using function

`pmax(Cars$A,Cars$B)`

But it gave me this result - **5,7,8,10,15,22,50,60**

The result I want - **5,7,15,22,60**

Comment: What about `Cars$A[Cars$A >= Cars$B]`

Comment: It should be `pmax.int` (or rather `pmax`) not `p.max` - I made this edit.

Comment: @thothal, thank you for the edit. Now it looks clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pmax` is the parallel maximun, from `?pmax`

> Returns the (regular or *p*arallel) maxima and minima of the input
>        values.
>      ‘pmax*()’ and ‘pmin*()’ take one or more vectors as arguments,
>        recycle them to common length and return a single vector giving
>        the *‘parallel’* maxima (or minima) of the argument vectors.

That is, at each position it returns the larger value - that's what you see in your output.

What you want is `Cars$A[Cars$A >= Cars$B]`

Comment: Glad to help, would you accept the answer then as well?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a sample data from `mtcars`

```
data("mtcars")
newdf <- data.frame(cars = rownames(mtcars)[1:10])
newdf$A <- sample(1:10,replace = T)
newdf$B <- sample(1:10,replace = T)
newdf$out <- ifelse(newdf$A >= newdf$B, newdf$A, newdf$B)
```

Output:

```
> head(newdf)
               cars  A B out
1         Mazda RX4  9 9   9
2     Mazda RX4 Wag 10 9  10
3        Datsun 710  6 3   6
4    Hornet 4 Drive  3 6   2
5 Hornet Sportabout  4 5   2
6           Valiant  2 2   9
```