# compare values in two rows of a dataframe, if they have the same value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

A lot of questions been asked about similar topic but none seem to work for me. The closest one are [In a dataframe, I want to compare column A and column B and extract value in which A >= B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121314/in-a-dataframe-i-want-to-compare-column-a-and-column-b-and-extract-value-in-whi). I need to find matching values in one column and if they are the same.
In the case of this example, I want to get rid of all the suppliers that do not have the biggest number of orders placed.
At this point nothing that i have tried seem to do the trick.

Here is a toy dataset to illustrate the problem:

```
 data = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : ['001', '001', '001', '001', '002', '002', '002', '003', '003', '003'],
                     'Supplier' : ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABZ', 'ANA', 'ABA', 'ABC', 'ASS', 'ASS', 'ASS', 'ASS'],
                     'BuyPrice' : [7,7,7,8,7,5,7,7,7,7],
                     'Quantity' : [200,20,50,40,210,47,66,53,100,60]})
```

and what I am trying to achieve is:

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['001', '002', '003'],
                     'main_supplier' : ['ABC', 'ABA', 'ASS'],
                     'BuyPrice' : [7,7,7]})
```

where data_result['BuyPrice'] is the price associated with the main supplier

I have been able to do this:

```
dd = pd.DataFrame()
dd['Id'] = data1['Id']
dd['number_of_orders'] = pd.DataFrame(data1['Quantity']).applymap(lambda x: len(x))
dd['BuyPrice'] = pd.DataFrame(data1['BuyPrice']).applymap(lambda x: np.mean(x))
dd['Supplier'] = data1['Supplier']

for x in dd['Id']:
    if dd['Id'] == dd['Id']:

        dd['Principal_supplier'] = np.where(np.where((dd['number_of_orders'][x] > dd['number_of_order'][x-1]), 'Yes'))

    else:
        dd['Principal_supplier'] = 'No'
drop_Secondary_supplier = dd[dd['Principal_supplier' != 'Yes']].drop()
```

and i get the following error:

```
    self.__class__.__name__
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I am struggling a lot of with the logic of comparing the "number of orders" if and only if the "id" are the same.

Any help would be huge!

Comment: I try run your code and not working. Can you explain more your output DataFrame? `'BuyPrice' : [7,5,7]` ?

Comment: i made a typo, I adjusted it. In the code I calculate it differently, as in my real dataset, the buy price may differ although the supplier is the same

Comment: What is your logic of data cleanning? Which observations you want to keep? I mean  I am confused about your `data_result`

Comment: i want to get rid of all the suppliers that do not constitute the biggest number of orders, in the goal of saving only the "principal supplier"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby based on Id and get the index of it and display the corresponding data. It's pretty much self explanatory. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
 data.loc[data.groupby('Id')['Quantity'].idxmax(), ['Id', 'BuyPrice', 'Supplier']]
```